# Check presence of multiple keywords and create another column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'meds': ['Calcium Acetate','insulin GLARGINE -- LANTUS -  inJECTable','amoxicillin  1 g  + clavulanic acid  200 mg ','digoxin  - TABLET'],
                   'details':['DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject','DOSE:   12 unit(s)  -  ON  -  SC (SubCutaneous)','-- AUGMENTIN -  inJECTable','DOSE:   62.5 mcg  -  Every other morning  -  PO'],
                   'extracted':['Calcium Acetate 667 mg Inject','insulin GLARGINE -- LANTUS 12 unit(s) -  SC (SubCutaneous)','amoxicillin  1 g  + clavulanic acid  200 mg -- AUGMENTIN','digoxin  - TABLET 62.5 mcg PO/Tube']})
df['concatenated'] = df['meds'] + " "+ df['details']
```

What I would like to do is

a) Check whether **all of the individual keywords** from `extracted` column is present in the `concatenated` column.

b) If present, assign `1` to the `output` column else `0`

c) Assign the not found keyword in `issue` column as shown below

So, I was trying something like below

```
df['clean_extract'] = df.extracted.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)') 
 #the above regex is incorrect. I would like to clean the text (remove all symbols except spaces and retain a clean text)
df['keywords'] = df.clean_extract.str.split(' ') #split them into keywords
def value_present(row):   #check whether each of the keyword is present in `concatenated` column
    if isinstance(row['keywords'], list):
        for keyword in row['keywords']:
            return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['output'] = df[df.apply(value_present, axis=1)][['concatenated', 'keywords']].head()
```

If you think its useful to clean `concatenated` column as well, its fine. Am only interested in finding the presence of all keywords.

**Is there any efficient and elegant approach to do this on 7-8 million records**?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. Red color indicates missing term between `extracted` and `concatenated` column. So, its assigned 0 and keyword is stored in `issue` column.

[image]

Comment: You'd probably have to forget about regex if you have millions of data to process and you need speed. Else, before splitting into words, run a `df.extracted.str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')` or `re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us zip the columns `extracted` and `concatenated` and for each pair map it to a function `f` which computes the `set` difference and returns the result accordingly:

```
def f(x, y):
    s = set(x.split()) - set(y.split())
    return [0, ', '.join(s)] if s else [1, np.nan]

df[['output', 'issue']] = [f(*s) for s in zip(df['extracted'], df['concatenated'])]
```

---

```
   output    issue
0       1      NaN
1       1      NaN
2       1      NaN
3       0  PO/Tube
```

Comment: I actually got this error `KeyError: "None of [Index(['output', 'issue'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: @TheGreat I think you are using old pandas version..You can try `df[['output', 'issue']] = pd.DataFrame([f(*s) for s in zip(df['extracted'], df['concatenated'])])`

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to execute line by line. May I know what does this line do? `return [0, ', '.join(s)] if s else [1, np.nan]`

Comment: Sure..`return [0, ', '.join(s)] if s else [1, np.nan]` is just a syntactical sugar(`one liner`) for multi-line `if-else` statement..you can see the same code with multiline `if-else`  statement [`here`](https://repl.it/repls/UnwieldyClassicProcessors)

Comment: @TheGreat Please check [`here`](https://ideone.com/mnBADc)

Comment: @TheGreat Already working on your question :D